# MYSQL ordenar consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguientes consultas a mysql:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY categoria_ordre ASC') as $row_cat) { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 
                    <?php echo $row_cat['categoria_nom']; ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row columnes-temporades">
                    <?php foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM competicio WHERE competicio_categoria = '.$row_cat['categoria_id'].' ') as $row_comp) {
                        $sql_temp = 'SELECT * FROM temporada WHERE temporada_id = '.$row_comp['competicio_temporada'].' ORDER BY temporada_ordre DESC ';
                        $res_temp = $mysqli->query($sql_temp);
                        $row_temp = $res_temp->fetch_assoc();
                    ?>
                        <div class="columnes">
                            <a href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=<?php echo $row_comp['competicio_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">
                                <?php echo $row_temp['temporada_nom']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Cuando quiero mostrar el campo `$row_temp['temporada_nom']` no me sale ordenado por el criterio del select, alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal ?

Gracias.

PD: Adjunto capturas de las tablas:

Tabla competicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambla temporada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo `competicio_temporada` de la tabla competicio, es una llave foranea del campo `temporada_id` de la tabla temporada.

Imagen del resultado que me muestra actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79557/discussion-on-question-by-vieri-mysql-ordenar-consulta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio veo algún tipo de redundancia entre categorías y competiciones, pero bueno suponiendo que el modelo así te funcione y sea estable, he aquí un replanteamiento usando una sola `QUERY` y haciendo un poco de magialabarismo™ con los group y joins:

`SQL`

```
SELECT
   categoria_nom,
   competicio_nom,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tempo ORDER BY ordre DESC SEPARATOR ',') as temporadas
  FROM (
    SELECT
       t.temporada_ordre as ordre,
       CONCAT(t.temporada_nom, "|", c.competicio_id) as tempo,
       c.competicio_nom,
       c.competicio_categoria
     FROM temporada t
       INNER JOIN competicio c ON c.competicio_temporada = t.temporada_id
  ) AS tc
  LEFT JOIN categoria ca ON ca.categoria_id = competicio_categoria
  GROUP BY competicio_nom, competicio_categoria, categoria_ordre, categoria_nom
  ORDER BY categoria_ordre
  ;
```

En el select interno joineamos `temporada` y `competicio`, guardamos el `competicio_id` asociado a cada `temporada_nom` concatenando ambos con un `|`

En el select externo joineamos `categoria` para saber el nombre y el `categoria_ordre`.

En este paso también agrupamos por `competicio_nom` y `competicio_categoria` guardando la asociación de las temporadas (del select interno) usando `GROUP_CONCAT` donde ademas le decimos que ordene esta lista por `temporada_ordre`.

Finalmente ordenamos por `categoria_ordre`.

Esto nos daría por resultado algo así:

| categoria_nom | competicio_nom | temporadas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| categoria 1 | 3a catala grup 5 | 2017-18|69,2016-17|1,2015-16|5,2014-15|3,2013-14|4,2012-13|6 |
| categoria 3 | 2a regio grup 5 | 2010-11|8,2009-10|9,2008-09|10,2007-08|11,2006-07|12,2005-06|13,2004-05|14 |
| categoria 5 | 3a regio grup 5 | 2010-11|30,2009-10|31,2008-09|32,2007-08|33 |
| categoria 6 | 2a catala grup 4 | 2014-15|54,2013-14|55,2012-13|56,2011-12|57 |

`php` aquí simulo el resultado en un array (descomentar el query y comentar el array)

```
<?php
/*
$result = $mysqli->query('
SELECT
   categoria_nom,
   competicio_nom,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tempo ORDER BY ordre DESC SEPARATOR ",") as temporadas
  FROM (
    SELECT
       t.temporada_ordre as ordre,
       CONCAT(t.temporada_nom, "|", c.competicio_id) as tempo,
       c.competicio_nom,
       c.competicio_categoria
     FROM temporada t
       INNER JOIN competicio c ON c.competicio_temporada = t.temporada_id
  ) AS tc
  LEFT JOIN categoria ca ON ca.categoria_id = competicio_categoria
  GROUP BY competicio_nom, competicio_categoria, categoria_ordre, categoria_nom
  ORDER BY categoria_ordre
  ;
');
$resultados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//*/
$resultados = [
['categoria_nom' =>'categoria 1', 'competicio_nom' => '3a catala grup 5', 'temporadas' => '2017-18|69,2016-17|1,2015-16|5,2014-15|3,2013-14|4,2012-13|6'],
['categoria_nom' =>'categoria 3', 'competicio_nom' => '2a regio grup 5', 'temporadas' => '2010-11|8,2009-10|9,2008-09|10,2007-08|11,2006-07|12,2005-06|13,2004-05|14'],
['categoria_nom' =>'categoria 5', 'competicio_nom' => '3a regio grup 5', 'temporadas' => '2010-11|30,2009-10|31,2008-09|32,2007-08|33'],
['categoria_nom' =>'categoria 6', 'competicio_nom' => '2a catala grup 4', 'temporadas' => '2014-15|54,2013-14|55,2012-13|56,2011-12|57']
];

$categorias = [];
foreach ($resultados as $row_res) :
  $cat_nom = array_shift($row_res); // conseguimos el nombre de categoria
  $categorias[$cat_nom][] = $row_res; // armamos array con el resto de campos
endforeach;

// var_dump($resultados, $categorias);
?>
<div class="container">
  <?php foreach($categorias as $categoria_nom=>$row_cat) { // categorias
  ?><h2><?php echo $categoria_nom; ?></h2>
    <hr />
    <?php foreach($row_cat as $row_comp) { // competiciones
    ?><div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3
        class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> <?php
        echo $row_comp['competicio_nom'];
        ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row columnes-temporades">
          <?php // extraigo las temporadas a un array
          $temporadas = explode(',', $row_comp['temporadas']);
          foreach($temporadas as $row_temp) { // temporadas
            $tempo = explode('|', $row_temp);
            $temporada_nom = $tempo[0]; // el nombre
            $competicio_id = $tempo[1]; // el id asociado
            ?><div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=<?php echo $competicio_id; ?>"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              ><?php echo $temporada_nom; ?></a>
            </div>
          <?php } // temporadas
          ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php } // competiciones?>
<?php } // categorias?>
</div>
```

Primero se arma un `array` bidimensional para las categorías.

Se mantienen los `foreach` mas uno externo para las categorías, aquí es donde veo algo medio extraño en la relación entre categorías y competiciones.

Los `foreachs` internos se arman sobre `arrays` usando `explode`para separar los datos por `,` (temporadas) y por `|` (`temporada_nom` y `competicio_id`)

html de salida es algo así (los títulos de categoría parecen reduntantes pues en la muestra que usé de datos no había dos competiciones en la misma categoría):

```css
.row.columnes-temporades{text-align:center}
.columnes {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  

<div class="container">
  <h2>categoria 1</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3
        class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 3a catala grup 5</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row columnes-temporades">
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=69"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2017-18</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=1"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2016-17</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=5"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2015-16</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=3"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2014-15</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=4"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2013-14</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=6"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2012-13</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <h2>categoria 3</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3
        class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 2a regio grup 5</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row columnes-temporades">
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=8"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2010-11</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=9"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2009-10</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=10"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2008-09</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=11"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2007-08</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=12"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2006-07</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=13"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2005-06</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=14"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2004-05</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <h2>categoria 5</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3
        class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 3a regio grup 5</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row columnes-temporades">
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=30"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2010-11</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=31"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2009-10</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=32"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2008-09</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=33"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2007-08</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <h2>categoria 6</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3
        class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> 2a catala grup 4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row columnes-temporades">
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=54"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2014-15</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=55"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2013-14</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=56"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2012-13</a>
            </div>
          <div class="columnes">
              <a
              href="classificacio-veure.php?competicio_id=57"
              class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
              >2011-12</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En resumen, un ejercicio interesante de agrupar, concatenar y ordenar en el SQL y luego desagrupar para mostrar en el PHP. Espero le sirva.

El fiddle actualizado con el registro problemático `(69, '3a catala grup 5', 1, 18),`
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/970c21/1

Comment: El query debe haber algo mal, con respeto a mis datos de la base de datos, ya que no me muestra nada, tengo que revisarlo bien ya que si hago un var_dump de `$resultados`me devuelve un null

Comment: fijate el fiddle, yo me inventé la tabla `categorias`

Comment: Si, lo curioso es que si hago el query directamente en el phpmyadmin, en la pesataña del sql, funciona perfecto ...

Comment: fijate si no le erré en la sintaxis de la edición `$result = $msqli->query(...`, luego `$resultados=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Pues no hay surte ... sigue sin mostrarme nada, estoy revisando todo para que no haya ningún error, y lo veo todo bien ... Como te dije la ejecución del sql funciona bien, debe ser algo depués del query que no consigo averiguar que es ...

Comment: ok, le había pifiado en unas comillas simples. ahora debería funcionar. también agregué los campos al GROUP BY para que mysql 5.7 no proteste

Comment: Perfecto !!! Ahora funciona todo bien. Muchísimas gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

Sólo cambia **DESC** por **ASC**.

```
$sql_temp = 'SELECT * FROM temporada WHERE temporada_id = '.$row_comp['competicio_temporada'].' ORDER BY temporada_ordre ASC';
```